# Is there a way to edit Parse database entries through the dashboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pfquery

Is it possible to edit a string in a class on the Parse dashboard? For example, I have the following code:

```
PFObject *announcement1 = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Announcement1"];
announcement1[@"Body"] = @"Changes to training progression";
[announcement1 saveInBackground];
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is treat Parse like a database. I create a PFObject, call the class "Announcement1" and display the string "Body" in a label.

I've already created the query to pull the "Body" string in the label:

```
PFQuery *announcement1Query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Announcement1"];
[announcement1Query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"GvuO1ZUYwR"];
NSString *announcement1BodyText = announcement1[@"Body"];
announcement1Label.text = announcement1BodyText;
```

Now my question is, would it be possible to then go into my Parse dashboard and edit the "Body" string so as to update the label live with new information each time? If not, what would be the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks, Mustafa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can update data in parse using dashboard. Parse doesn't support realtime DB, so you need to query the object or refresh object again to see the real data.